# Проверка даты в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь должен ввести дату в формате дд.мм.гггг, но если дата введена неверно (например введено 31 февраля или введенная дата больше текущей или пользователь ввел буквы и т.д.) выводиться ошибка. Как это реализовать?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime(input_string, "%d.%m.%Y")` и так выведет сообщение об ошибке если введенную строку не получится преобразовать в дату... Уточните суть вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [вот такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216257/1597497) приём:

```
import time
date = input('Date (mm/dd/yyyy): ')
try:
  valid_date = time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
except ValueError:
  print('Invalid date!')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
get_date = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m.%Y').date() <= datetime.today().date()
assert get_date('14.09.2019')  # OK
assert get_date('15.09.2019')  # AssertionError
assert get_date('32.09.2019')  # ValueError: time data '32.09.2019' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
```